# facebook, how to get to a application page?

Tags: php, facebook

i've setup a application that has a path to:

```
www.some_page.com/index.php
```

on the page i have a link that goes to:

```
www.some_page.com/picture.php?number=123
```

this page displays in the same fb iframe application.

My question is how to get to `www.some_page.com/picture.php?number=123` from an outside link?

if i just link to it it will take me to the page but outside the facebook app, and i need t to take me to that page inside the app..

i guess that when i click on that link i have to send the user first to accept the app access then got o that page ?!

any ideas?

Thanks

edit 1:
 ** what i want is to place a link to `www.some_page.com/picture.php?number=123` on another site and redirect me that page inside the facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options to set a facebook app:

- embed your www.some_page.com inside an iframe (this will make sure all your links will stay inside)
- Follow this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ and make sure you don't have target="_blank" this is a better option and your links should open in the same scope.

Comment: hey, they do open in the same scope, but what i want is to place a link to `www.some_page.com/picture.php?number=123` on another site and redirect me that page inside the facebook app

Comment: So you need to have a rule in your server side (or a rule in .htaccess) that take www.some_page.com/picture.php?number=123 from your server and point it to your FB app url.